# When do NPC's join poker games in RDR2?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

What are the mechanics that dictate whether additional NPC's will join an ongoing poker game in Red Dead Redemption 2? Sometimes there is a revolving door of NPC's joining and leaving the game, and sometimes I end up playing heads up against a single NPC with a heavy chip lead for hours and hours. Are the rules that govern these behaviors known?